# How can i close the connection(req) once i received the response from api call Node js

Tags: node.js

```
var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
var msg = '';
res.setEncoding('utf8');
res.on('data', function(chunk) {
msg += chunk;
});
res.on('end', function() {
//

}); 
res.on('error', function() {


}); 

});
req.write(data);

req.end();
```

I have to close the connection once the api call successfully completed in node js

Answer (score 0):

`res.on('end', function() { req.end() });`

https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_request_end_data_encoding_callback

Comment: req.end()-its not closing the connection in our case.i am facing ETIMEDOUT error while calling api.How to close the connection properly